# Bean gets initialized but injection throws npe

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jax-rs, javabeans

I am creating a bean using a configuration file. The bean gets initialized as during server startup I have a debug point inside it and it gets triggered. When my restApi calls the handler method it throws NPE where coinResponse is null. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

configurationFile

```
package com.foo.service.handler;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo.service")
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CoinResponse getCoinResponse() {
        return new CoinResponse();
    }
}
```

handlerFile

```
package com.foo.service.handler;
public class DetailsHandler {

    @Inject
    CoinResponse getCoinResponse;
    public List<CoinResponse> getCoinDetails() {
        System.out.println(getCoinResponse.getClass());
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>foosvc</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fomo.service" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chances are that `DetailsHandler` is not defined in Spring.

Dependency Injection (`@Inject`) can happen only inside classes used by Spring. 
Please try to create a no-ops constructor in `DetailsHandler` class and put a breakpoint there.

Depending on your spring configuration you should probably make annotate it with `@Component` or one of its stereotypes (like `@Controller` for example)